# Do tools exist to help me translate a real world object to a LEGO design?

Tags: tools

It can be a big challenge to create a design for a large object. Are there techniques or tools to simplify this, and to help estimate numbers of blocks required?

Comment: You can convert your LEGO design to a virtual object! http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=56336

Comment: If you have a 3D model of the real world object, you could check out this question: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-3d-model-into-a-lego-sculpture/3075#3075

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Lego Digital Designer](http://ldd.lego.com/) (~140mb, Mac and PC) is quite useful for creating 3D designs. I haven't personally used it that much but it is quite a powerful tool. It will tell you the number of bricks used in a model as well.

At a pinch, MS Paint (pixel-based), Google Sketchup (find some templates for bricks) and Minecraft could even be used for planing builds.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as asked. Or  explain what advantage LDD has?