# Where can I find a copy of read_binvox.cc

Tags: software

Can you upload your read_binvox.cc please?

I tried to find out some on the net but at each time I would like to paste the program on my code blocks the program had an error (0xc000007b).

Comment: I've updated these broken links assuming that you are referencing this answer: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/3075/708 In the future, it's simplest to just leave a comment on the answer when requesting updates like this.

Answer (score 1):

This software is now available here:

http://www.patrickmin.com/binvox/read_binvox.cc